# Cannot add image to cache in watchOS 2?

Tags: image, caching, watchos-2

In watchOS 2 `WKInterfaceDevice` class, there is no declarations of `-addCachedImage:`. If you want to use it, it will mark your code as not available.

It has a `cachedImages` property, though. I wonder where is the API to cache images in watchOS 2? Thank you for your help!

This happens for watchOS 2 beta 4 and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Image caching is not supported in watchOS 2."

From:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceImage